# Where's the exe that handles the Bluetooth tray icon?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, taskbar, notification-area

Where could I find the exe/process/dll that handles this pesky [colored tray icon of Bluetooth tray icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMLvf.png). I am very customized person, so I want to customize it, break it open and replace those resources with my redesigned ones to make that Bluetooth icon in line with that other Windows 10 tray icons
Tell me where I could find it? Thanks